# Restructuring/Sorting Data from Database output

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file from a webbased database that stores bills of materials and it indentures it by an id and a nhaid. Ideally, it would export the data as it's seen in the database, but that's not always the case. I am writing some macros to help with the restructuring of these boms. There's no indenture on these exports, so I wrote a macro to create the indenture and then reorder the rows that were given a value of 0. It would simply move them to where they seemed to go. And it worked for the most part but further testing revealed that there were some flaws.

So I started writing a different macro, with the thought of just going through each line(id) and find each and every nhaid that points to it and move/cut and insert it underneath it. I ran into an error when it woudl try to cut and insert on the same row, which is what the first if statement does.

```
for i = 3 to lr
    lvli = cells(i,2).value
    idi = cells(i,3).value
    nhai = cells(i,5).value
    for j = i+1 to lr
        nhaj = cells(j,5).value
        if nhaj = cells(j-1,3).value then
            cells(j,2).value = cells(j-1,2).value + 1
        elseif nhaj <> "" and nhaj = idi then
            set found = sheets(1).columns(3).find(what:=nhaj,lookin:xlvalues, _              
                lookat:=xlwhole)
            rwno = found.row
            row(j).select
            selection.cut
            rows(rwno+1).select
            selection.insert
            cells(j,2).value = lvli + 1
       end if
    next j
next i
```

So, there's another for loop, in the beginning, that checks to see if the nhaid is blank and moves it to row 3, as those will be the top most assembly.

```
for i = 3 to lr
    nhai = cells(i,5).value
    if i = 3 and nhai = "" and cells(i,2).value = "" then
        cells(i,2).value = 0
    if i > 3 and nhai = "" then
        cells(i,2).value = 0
        rows(i).select
        selection.cut
        rows(3).select
        selection.insert
    end if
next i
```

The macro works, for the most part but upon checking the excel file, there are some rows that have a value in column 2 and others that have the same nhai that don't have a value in column 2. I thought that maybe the macro was ending early, but I don't think so, because there's missing data in many spots. Then I thought well maybe it's skipping over these, but I don't think so either, because there's no exit for. It's kind of difficult to test the macro at it's fullest, because the files can be large and it can hours to run.

Comment: Difficult to make any suggestions or even really to understand the problem, without any examples of what your data looks like.

Comment: Might be a lot less painful to do your data extract and sort in power query.